# Import static data into Power Bi from a csv file

Tags: csv, import, powerbi, refresh

I what to import into a Power Bi Desktop report a CSV file with static data (data that will not be refreshed) from my machine. The report has data from an Azure SQL DB and I need to schedule refresh for that once the report is published. The problem that I have is that the report detects in the CSV file a connection and requests to create a Gateway in order to refresh. There is any way that I can import this data only once and the report doesn't try to refresh it?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to create a gateway, you can either

- If the CSV is not very large, you can create a custom table in Power
  BI that is identical to your CSV file.
- You can host the file in the cloud and create a connection to it (Ex:
  Sharepoint Online)

Hope this helps.

Cheers
SS

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My file is big, I can't introduce de data manually, I know the cloud option but what I wanted to know was if I can import the file just like if I create the table manually and copy the data from the file directly. For example, in the first option, I would have to write all the data by hand (unless there is an option to create the table schema and import the data automatically). I suppose by your answer that there is not another way, that's right?

Comment: Any way to import a csv to a custom table?